# URLs not found after configuring virtual host on XAMPP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xampp

I have a `$.get()` AJAX call to `response.php` but after configuring a virtual host on XAMPP I get this error :

> jquery.js:9631 GET http://mipl.local/response.php?operation=delete_node&code=Power_source&text=fsfsfsssddfsfs 404 (Not Found)

'mipl.local' is the server name after configuration. Here is my code where I make the AJAX call:

```
$.get('response.php?operation=delete_node', { 
 'code': data.node.parent,
 'text': data.node.text 
});
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: This sounds like an XAMPP configuration problem, not a JS one

Comment: but everything works  except this one

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with adding the global url not the short one